# Rapidly modifying Python app in K8S pod for debugging

Tags: docker, debugging, kubernetes

---

## Background

I have a large Python service that runs on a desktop PC, and I need to have it run as part of a K8S deployment. I expect that I will have to make several small changes to make the service run in a deployment/pod before it will work.

---

## Problem

So far, if I encounter an issue in the Python code, it takes a while to update the code, and get it deployed for another round of testing. For example, I have to:

- Modify my Python code.
- Rebuild the Docker container (which includes my Python service).
- `scp` the Docker container over to the Docker Registry server.
- `docker load` the image, update tags, and push it to the Registry back-end DB.
- Manually kill off currently-running pods so the deployment restarts all pods with the new Docker image.

This involves a lot of lead time each time I need to debug a minor issue. Ideally, I've prefer being able to just modify the copy of my Python code already running on a pod, but I can't kill it (since the Python service is the default app that is launched, with `PID=1`), and K8S doesn't support restarting a pod (to my knowledge). Alternately, if I kill/start another pod, it won't have my local changes from the pod I was previously working on (which is by design, of course; but doesn't help with my debug efforts).

---

## Question

Is there a better/faster way to rapidly deploy (experimental/debug) changes to the container I'm testing, without having to spend several minutes recreating container images, re-deploying/tagging/pushing them, etc? If I could find and mount (read-write) the Docker image, that might help, as I could edit the data within it directly (i.e. new Python changes), and just kill pods so the deployment re-creates them.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main options: one is to use a tool that reduces or automates that flow, the other is to develop locally with something like Minikube.

For the first, there are a million and a half tools but Skaffold is probably the most common one.

For the second, you do something like `( eval $(minikube docker-env) && docker build -t myimagename . )` which will build the image directly in the Minikube docker environment so you skip steps 3 and 4 in your list entirely. You can combine this with a tool which detects the image change and either restarts your pods or updates the deployment (which restarts the pods).

Also FWIW using `scp` and `docker load` is very not standard, generally that would be combined into `docker push`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your pain point is the container relied on the python code. You can find a way to exclude the source code from docker image build phase.

For my experience, I will create a docker image only include python package dependencies, and use `volume` to map source code dir to the container path, so you don't need to rebuild the image if no dependencies are added or removed.

## Example

I have not much experience with k8s, but I believe it must be more or less the same as `docker run`.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-stretch

COPY ./python/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
```

### Docker container

`scp` deploy your code to the server, and map your host source path to the container source path like this:

```
docker run -it -d -v /path/to/your/python/source:/path/to/your/server/source --name python-service your-image-name
```

With volume mapping, your container no longer depend on the source code, you can easily change your source code without rebuilding your image.